# Is there a way to read comments/notes of a cell in an excel file with ParseExcel/ParseXLSX?

Tags: excel, perl, parsing, parseexcel

```
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
...
...
my $cell     = $worksheet->get_cell($row,$column);
$cell_value  = $name->value();
```

This gets the value stored in the cell. If I have comments/notes associated with this cell, how can I fetch it?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could convert the `.xls` to an `.xlsx` file. The latter is a zip file that you can extract. The XML archive file `xl/comments1.xml` contains the comments for sheet 1.

Comment: @HåkonHægland if they do that, there's probably a method to use with Spreadheet::XLSX too.

Comment: After having done some investigation into the module code it looks like this isn't implemented. Sorry. You can see if the workbook would print comments, but that's it.